# How is it possible to install windows 10 on arm?

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, windows

I would like to install Windows 10 on my Rapsberry pi 3, but I can only find windows 10 IOT. I am looking for the normal desktop Windows 10 on arm:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/P4171

I would like to run some native x86 windows apps, which is not possible on raspbian. (Only possible with ExaGear, but it is not a free software)

How is it possible to download and install the ARM version of Windows 10 to raspberry 3?

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: https://twitter.com/NTAuthority/status/961366478292430849

Comment: @AlbertoRivelli There is no explanation how he did it. Maybe it is just fake

Comment: I don't think it's fake, Windows on ARM it's coming and with some hacks you can run it on the RPi3. He is using Windows 10 Enterprise for ARM64 and he patched some code with assembler. Also as you saw he had problems with a check on the CPU that made the OS shut down after some time. There is also a discussion here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=204993&p=1271113

Comment: @joan I've put Windows for ARM on a Raspberry Pi 4. Even did a simple Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition app targeting ARM64, installed it, and ran it. See this SO post about my experience: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600092/support-for-windows-10-desktop-applications-on-arm-mfc-and-com-and-opos-work

Answer (score 1):

Someone ported 64-bit Tiano Core UEFI to Raspberry Pi, and it can boot full Windows 10 ARM64 at the moment. If you want to give it a try, the project is [hosted on github](https://github.com/andreiw/RaspberryPiPkg). Drivers are really slow at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Windows 10 for ARM on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 4 GB of RAM and tried running sample applications built with Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition targeting ARM64 successfully. What I had to do was download the Windows 10 components from the Microsoft servers and build a Windows 10 from those components using a script I also downloaded.

I'm pretty sure that trying this with a Raspberry Pi 3 would be pretty miserable. I think you need at least 4 GB of RAM for a reasonable experience. And I used an SSD drive rather than using an SD card for storage.

It's been a few months since I did this however here are a couple of places to start.

[Tom's Hardware - How to Install Windows 10 on a Raspberry Pi 4](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/install-windows-10-raspberry-pi)

[How to install Windows 10 on Raspberry Pi 4](https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/07/24/install-windows-10-on-raspberry-pi/)

[Ars Technica - New script makes it easy(ish) to put Windows 10 or 11 on a Raspberry Pi](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/09/new-script-makes-it-easyish-to-put-windows-10-or-11-on-a-raspberry-pi/)

[MUD - How to Install Windows 10 and 11 on a Raspberry Pi 4 the Easy Way](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-install-windows-10-and-11-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-the-easy-way/)

I've done some simple programming experiments to answer a question that I had. See this SO post of my results, [stackoverflow - Support for Windows 10 desktop applications on ARM - MFC and COM and OPOS work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600092/support-for-windows-10-desktop-applications-on-arm-mfc-and-com-and-opos-work)

See also this ExplainingComputers video, [Windows 11 ARM on Raspberry Pi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGF_HaSdFyA)

See also this ExplainingComputer video, [ARM Windows 11 on RK3588 SBC (Orange Pi 5)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-A13-VYS6Q)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Desktop does only run on ARM devices where the manufacturer has a **close cooperation** with Microsoft and is **willing to invest resources** into porting and customizing. Raspberry Pi has **neither** cooperation nor resources for that. They are heavily invested and interested in Raspbian and the Linux kernel only.

Please have a look at the partly open-sourced Raspberry Pi BSP of IoT Core to get an idea what Microsoft is willing and able to do without explicit cooperation from OEMs.

Comment: As the OP mentions running x86 applications you may want to mention that even if the full windows 10 version was provided it would still be a version for arm and would't run x86 applicationss at all

Comment: I believe newest Win10 Desktop for ARM releases will contain an x86 emulator. How well that works is anyones guess.

Comment: ARM64 Win10 can run x86 applications with Windows On Windows AArch64 (WOW64), just like amd64 versions.